# Issue with AWS CLI and SSH Connection in GitHub Actions Workflow

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, github-actions, devops

I am facing an issue with my GitHub Actions workflow while deploying my application to an EC2 instance using the AWS CLI and SSH. The workflow involves setting up AWS CLI credentials, copying files to the EC2 instance using SCP, and executing commands on the instance using SSH. However, I'm encountering an error during the SSH step:

```
Host key verification failed.
lost connection
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

I have already verified that the AWS CLI credentials are correctly set up in the workflow. The issue seems to be related to the SSH connection to the EC2 instance.

Here's the relevant part of my workflow YAML:

```
- name: Deploy to EC2
  run: |
    aws configure set aws_access_key_id <access_key>
    aws configure set aws_secret_access_key <secret_access_key>
    aws configure set default.region <region>

    scp -r -i ../Fial.pem ./ ubuntu@<instance_ip>:~/app
    ssh -i ../Fial.pem ubuntu@<instance_ip> 'cd ~/app && composer install --no-dev --optimize-autoloader && php artisan migrate --seed'
```

Error in deatail

```
Run aws configure set aws_access_key_id AKIA5I76TBNTHW4Z5TV5
  aws configure set aws_access_key_id AKIA5I76TBNTHW4Z5TV5
  aws configure set aws_secret_access_key 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
  aws configure set default.region ap-south-1
  
  scp -r -i ../Fial.pem ./ ubuntu@43.205.128.246:~/app
  ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i ../Fial.pem ubuntu@43.205.128.246 'cd ~/app && composer install --no-dev --optimize-autoloader && php artisan migrate --seed'
  shell: /usr/bin/bash --noprofile --norc -e -o pipefail {0}
Host key verification failed.
lost connection
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

Comment: If that's your real AWS keys, deactivate them immediately.

Comment: @jordanm It was :)

Comment: That error is entirely unrelated to the AWS CLI or your AWS access keys. Those API keys are not used for SSH connections at all. That error is almost certainly coming from the `scp` step, not the `ssh` step, because the `-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no` argument is specifically designed to avoid this error. You need to add the `-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no` argument to the `scp` command just like you did with the `ssh` command.

Answer (score 0):

The scp command is the culprit here. If the host key for the host you are trying to ssh to is not in the `~/.ssh/known_hosts` file, you'll get a prompt for whether to add the key to known_hosts or not. It cannot proceed any further than this unless you provide a response to this prompt. To avoid this, you can add `-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no` flag to your scp command and it will skip the host key checking.

As a side note, try to use `aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1` instead of using shell.